# Cast column values to list keeping the order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Parent': ['Stay home', "Stay home","Stay home", 'Go swimming', "Go swimming","Go swimming"],
                   'Child': ['Severe weather', "Severe weather", "Severe weather", 'Not Severe weather', "Not Severe weather", "Not Severe weather"],
                   'Child1':   ["Extreme rainy", "Extreme windy",   "Severe snow", "Sunny", "some windy", "No snow"]
                   })
```

I want to cast the `Child1` column to a list groupby the `child` column

So I am trying the following code:

```
def cast_to_list(df, col):
    return df.groupby('Child')[col].apply(list).tolist()

list5=cast_to_list(df1, 'Child1')
list5
```

Outcome:

```
[['Sunny', 'some windy', 'No snow'],
 ['Extreme rainy', 'Extreme windy', 'Severe snow']]
```

The expected outcome preserves the order of the values of `Child1` column:

So the expected outcome is the following:

```
  [['Extreme rainy', 'Extreme windy', 'Severe snow'],
     ['Sunny', 'some windy', 'No snow']]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort=False` in [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
def cast_to_list(df, col):
    return df.groupby('Child', sort=False)[col].apply(list).tolist()

list5 = cast_to_list(df1, 'Child1')
list5
```

Output:

```
[['Extreme rainy', 'Extreme windy', 'Severe snow'],
 ['Sunny', 'some windy', 'No snow']]
```